# set folder owner group

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, file-permissions, chown

I have application running on ubuntu 12.04 and when user submit file using submit form I got permission denied error. So it seems that user don't have permission to write. when I'm logged in as root and use `ls -l folder_name` it write

```
drwxrwxr-x   2 root root  4096 Dec  5 01:17 folder1
drwxrwxr-x   2 root root  4096 Dec  5 01:17 folder2
```

when I use `chown myuser folder_name` and repeat `ls -l folder_name` it gives me the same output so myuser is still not owner of the folders. How can I add myuser as owner of existing folders and all newly created folders inside existing folders.
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things to consider-

- owner is root so either 'sudo chown' or become root to do the change
- chown myuser:mygroup to change both the owner and group (or chgrp)
- from your question it sounds like this is from a web page, so it will probably need to be owned by apache:apache or whatever your webserver runs as
- you can't specify the owner of all newly (future) created folders inside these, just who has permissions (chmod) to create folders and then depends on what user is trying to do the creates.

the command is:

sudo chown -R apache:apache folder1

Comment: thanks @robm but can you extend your answer, what commands to use? And yes it's web page and it's apache